# ASP.NET MVC 404 handling and IIS7 <httpErrors>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7, iis-6

Good day!

I use strategy to handle 404 errors like this: [Error handling for ASP.NET MVC 2 and IIS 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545906/error-handling-for-asp-net-mvc-2-and-iis-7-0) or this: [How can I properly handle 404 in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404s-in-asp-net-mvc/620559#620559)

In short: I handle 404 as exception in `Global.asax` without adding any routing rules, if the exception is 404 I render special controller\action with error message.

On IIS6 it works with ASP.NET wildcard mapping. On IIS7 in integrated mode I need to add the following to the `Web.config` (where `/error/HttpError404` is my action with 404 page):

```
    <httpErrors>
        <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/error/HttpError404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/error/HttpError403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
```

Why? Routing works differently on IIS integrated mode and IIS6 wildcard mapping?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
According to my tests it seems that my error handling works and my 404 action is rendered, but it seems that IIS sees 404 response code (which I set programmatically in my 404 action)  and replace my page with default errors.

When I set `<httpErrors>` I got two hits for 404 page: one from exception handling in `Global.asax` and one from IIS.

Can this be the cause?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems I have fixed it by setting in `Web.config`:

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
```

Comment: I've had the same problem for months and this worked for me. Thanks for the update!

Comment: I know it's a bit late, but what has worked with me with MVC3 is using exisitingResponse="Replace"

Comment: Setting exisitingResponse="Replace" in system.webserver seems to be incompatible with <customErrors mode="On" /> in system.web. With both set, I get a 500 page without detail removed where previously I would see my custom error page.

I ended up using this solution instead -http://stackoverflow.com/a/9026941/678453

Comment: You little beauty :)  Thanks. Everyone,  be sure to put this inside <system.webServer>