# Error handling in asp.net mvc 3 doesn't work properly on the hosting 

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling

In my asp.net mvc 3 application I've done some error handling and I happy it working. It works properly on the local computer. But on the hosting  the iis perhaps substitute errors views by its own error pages. I think and I'm almost sure  it's because of `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors`.

But I set `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors` to `true;` and there's no effect.

web.config

```
<customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
```

Global.asax

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   var exception = Server.GetLastError();
   Response.Clear();
   Server.ClearError();
   Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
   Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

   var routeData = new RouteData();
   routeData.Values["controller"] = "Errors";
   routeData.Values["action"] = "ServerError";

   var httpException = exception as HttpException;
   if (httpException != null)
    {
       Response.StatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
       switch (Response.StatusCode)
        {
          case 403:
            routeData.Values["action"] = "Unathorized";
                       break;
          case 404:
            routeData.Values["action"] = "NotFound";
                        break;
                }
       }

 IController errorsController = new ErrorsController();
 var rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
 errorsController.Execute(rc);
}
```

How rewrite this code  to get IIS on the hosting handle errros as I want.

Comment: imho you wont get much answers since that's not the proper way to handle errors in MVC. I struggled a lot with a similar solution before I switched to proper error handling as I've just described here: http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/11/how-to-handle-errors-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033681/how-to-override-httperrors-section-in-web-config-asp-net-mvc3/8403396#8403396

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to derive from a controller base class, which will override the `OnException` method, and put all your error handling code there.