# Edit httpErrors section in web.config from code behind

Tags: c#, web-config, code-behind

Is it possible to edit the "httpErrors" in "system.webServer" section of a web.config file from code behind?

Im getting null value when using:

`ConfigurationSection test = (ConfigurationSection)config.GetSection("system.webServer/httpErrors");`

I would like to change the value of errorMode and existingResponse. Also remove any present "remove" or "error" declerations nested inside of "httpErrors".

From this:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="/ErrorPages/NotFound.aspx" />
</httpErrors>
```

To this:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" existingResponse="Auto" />
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033681/how-to-override-httperrors-section-in-web-config-asp-net-mvc3

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
var section = (ConnectionStringsSection)configuration.GetSection("connectionStrings");
section.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString = "Data Source=...";
configuration.Save();
```

For more info look at [Change a web.config programmatically with C# (.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260317/change-a-web-config-programmatically-with-c-sharp-net)